# Remove object from json w/ json.net

Tags: c#, json, wpf, json.net

I have a json file that looks like this:

**Json**

```
{
"Telephones": [
{
  "TapiLine": "XX Line",
  "SpeakerList": [
    {
      "Name": "Office",
      "Ip": "192.168.10.204",
      "Volume": "5"
    },
    {
      "Name": "Living",
      "Ip": "192.168.10.214",
      "Volume": "5"
    }
  ]
}
]
}
```

**Class**

```
class Result
{
    public List<Telephone> Telephones { get; set; }

    public Result()
    {
        Telephones = new List<Telephone>();
    }
}


class Telephone
{
    public string TapiLine { get; set; }
    public List<Speakers> SpeakerList { get; set; }

    public Telephone()
    {
        SpeakerList = new List<Speakers>();
    }
}

class Speakers
{

    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Ip { get; set; }
    public string Volume { get; set; }

}
```

**What I'd like to do**

I have a combination of `TapiLine` and `Ip` and I would like to remove that Object with the according Ip from the `SpeakerList`.

**What I have already**

```
foreach (var telephones in json.Telephones.ToArray())
{
if (telephones.TapiLine == tLine.Name)
{
    foreach (var speakers in telephones.SpeakerList)
    {

        if (speakers.Ip == CurrentEditIp)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("REMOVE ME: " + speakers.Ip + " FROM: " + tLine.Name);

            //UNTIL HERE IT'S FINE; THE REST IS JUST GUESSING...
            var docsToRemove = new Result
            {
                Telephones = new List<Telephone>
                {
                    new Telephone
                    {
                        TapiLine = tLine.Name,
                        SpeakerList = new List<Speakers>
                        {
                            new Speakers
                            {
                                Name = CurrentEditName,
                                Ip = CurrentEditIp,
                                Volume = "5"
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            };

            json.Remove(docsToRemove); //THIS DOES NOTHING
        }

    }

}
}
```

How could I remove the according object from `SpeakerList`?
Any hint appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can remove an object from a collection by using methods such as `Remove`, `RemoveAt`, `RemoveAll` or `RemoveRange`.

Check the below code snippets demonstrating it using a for loop iterating backward or by using LINQ.

1. [Remove Object From JSON using for loop (compile C# online link)](http://rextester.com/DAAQD9676)

   ```
   namespace JSON
   {
       using Newtonsoft.Json;
       using System.Collections.Generic;
       using System.Linq;

       class Program
       {
           static void Main(string[] args)
           {
               var json = "{\"Telephones\": [{ \"TapiLine\": \"XX Line\", \"SpeakerList\": [{ \"Name\": \"Office\", \"Ip\": \"192.168.10.204\", \"Volume\": \"5\" }, { \"Name\": \"Living\", \"Ip\": \"192.168.10.214\", \"Volume\": \"5\" }] }] }";
               var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json, typeof(Result)) as Result;

               for (int i = result.Telephones.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
               {
                   if (result.Telephones[i].TapiLine == "XX Line")
                   {
                       for (int j = result.Telephones[i].SpeakerList.Count - 1; j >= 0; j--)
                       {
                           if (result.Telephones[i].SpeakerList[j].Ip == "192.168.10.204")
                           {
                               result.Telephones[i].SpeakerList.RemoveAt(j);
                           }
                       }
                   }
               }

               json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(result);
               // write updated JSON back to the file
           }
       }

       class Result
       {
           public List<Telephone> Telephones { get; set; }

           public Result()
           {
               Telephones = new List<Telephone>();
           }
       }    

       class Telephone
       {
           public string TapiLine { get; set; }   
           public List<Speakers> SpeakerList { get; set; }

           public Telephone()
           {
               SpeakerList = new List<Speakers>();
           }
       }

       class Speakers
       {
           public string Name { get; set; }    
           public string Ip { get; set; }
           public string Volume { get; set; }    
       }
   }
   ```
2. [Remove Object From JSON using LINQ (compile C# online link)](http://rextester.com/XMYL36544)

   ```
   namespace JSON
   {
       using Newtonsoft.Json;
       using System.Collections.Generic;
       using System.Linq;

       class Program
       {
           static void Main(string[] args)
           {
               var json = "{\"Telephones\": [{ \"TapiLine\": \"XX Line\", \"SpeakerList\": [{ \"Name\": \"Office\", \"Ip\": \"192.168.10.204\", \"Volume\": \"5\" }, { \"Name\": \"Living\", \"Ip\": \"192.168.10.214\", \"Volume\": \"5\" }] }] }";
               var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json, typeof(Result)) as Result;
               result
                   .Telephones
                   .Where(x => x.TapiLine == "XX Line")
                   .ToList()
                   .ForEach(x => x.SpeakerList.RemoveAll(y => y.Ip == "192.168.10.204"));

               json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(result);
               // write updated JSON back to the file
           }
       }

       class Result
       {
           public List<Telephone> Telephones { get; set; }

           public Result()
           {
               Telephones = new List<Telephone>();
           }
       }

       class Telephone
       {
           public string TapiLine { get; set; }    
           public List<Speakers> SpeakerList { get; set; }

           public Telephone()
           {
               SpeakerList = new List<Speakers>();
           }
       }

       class Speakers
       {
           public string Name { get; set; }   
           public string Ip { get; set; }
           public string Volume { get; set; }    
       }
   }
   ```

Comment: Thanks! Took the first one, but I'm sure 2. option was also working!